# Can't access login screen, wp-login.php 404's

Tags: loop, wp-admin, redirect, login

When i navigate to `/wp-admin/` i am redirected to `wp-login.php` with the wp-admin URL in the `redirect_to` parameter. Like this:

```
http://www.domain.com/wp-admin
... goes to ...
http://www.domain.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.domain.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1
```

If i just navigate to `/wp-login.php/` i get an endless redirect loop.

Things i've tried:

- Removing the .htaccess file in the root
- Renaming the `/wp-content/plugins/` folder (to check if any plugins are messing things up)
- Renaming all cookie keys in `wp-config.php`
- Changing permissions of the wp-login.php file to 755

Those are solutions i've found through other forums. I haven't had any success with either of them.

Basically what happened is a few months ago i was editing the site theme, and everything was working then. I haven't logged in until today, and now that i tried logging in i was met by this error.

Any other ideas?

Comment: have you logged in? if you have, then have you checked your server's disk space?

Comment: You don't mention having swapped to the default theme, like leaving only `twentytwelve` inside the `/themes/` folder.

Comment: I just tried renaming the theme folder, it made no difference for the login behaviour. It just made the frontend completely blank, which was expected. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Try reinstalling WordPress by replacing all the core files. Make sure you don't touch the `/wp-content/` folder (and/or back it up). Perhaps something goofy has happened to one of the core files.

Edit:

Try checking permissions on `wp-login.php` - should be 644.

Comment: Nope, that didn't help. :( For the record, here is the url to the website: http://goo.gl/xa73c

Comment: Try refreshing permalinks? Settings -> Permalinks. Then try again.

Comment: updated answer. see if that helps?

Comment: I tried refreshing permalinks between every change, that didn't help. But i did solve it, and it was indeed related to the `wp-login.php` file, although i am not sure what exactly was wrong with it. What happened is i cloned the entire site down locally and tried to login, then i got a 404 for the `wp-login.php` file (i didn't get that before). So i checked and the file wasn't there. Then i checked the server, and the file was there. So i tried downloading it, but that didn't work (didn't have permissions!??). ...

Comment: ... Weird. So i just renamed the file, then uploaded a fresh copy of it, and now it works. The thing is, i've never touched the `wp-login.php` file before, so i don't know what initially changed the permissions of it. I did however change it to 755 (which turns out was wrong, but whatever) myself while trying to fix it.

Comment: Cool. Well it does sound like it could have been permissions-related. Sometimes ownership can change and get ugly when moving from one system to another. The name of the Apache user often changes, which generally needs to be the owner.